# "around the world" and "in some countries"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm wondering if it's natural to include both boldfaced phrases in the following. Do they present a contradiction?

> The critters are considered a “prohibited organism” in the US because they can cause diseases in humans and can wreak significant havoc in the environment if released in the wild. Despite this, people **around the world** eat the snails and keep them as pets **in some countries**.

Source added: https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/detroit-giant-african-snails-confiscated-trnd/index.html

Comment: I don't see how this might be contradictory.  Perhaps an alternate phrasing could be found to remove the redundancy. ...  Anyway, you forgot to indicate the source for your quote.   I'm guessing this is from CNN.  https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/detroit-giant-african-snails-confiscated-trnd/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a poorly written sentence, and is either contradictory or borderline bad grammar, depending on what the writer intended.

The contradictory way to understand it is that the impossible subject of *people around the world in some countries* eat snails and keep them as pets.

A more generous way to parse it is that people around the world eat snails, and people in some countries keep them as pets. This is questionable grammar because it requires the two subjects to share the word "people", but not the words "around the world". In rapid speech this would be a perfectly normal thing to say because you can't go back and edit, but in writing this is no good.

Comment: Yes - it would be better written as "people around the world eat the snails, and in some countries keep them as pets".

Comment: @KateBunting Not sure if that technically solves the problem. "keep them as pets" still lacks an explicit subject and it has to look to the first VP for one, which unfortunately happens to be "People around the world." The result: ... and in some countries, people around the world keep them as pets.